# Force scrollbars to show if content overflows

Tags: css

I have this div with the class feedback-rounds-container. It is a fixed height and width and sometimes the content overflows it. To make it obvious to the user, I force the scrollbar to appear, overriding the browser setting, but now it shows all the time, even if the content does not overflow the div.

I would like to get it to show all the time if the content overflows, but if the content doesn't overflow I don't want it to show at all. Is there any way to do this (hopefully in pure css)?

```css
.feedback-rounds-container {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 80px;
  width: 200px;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
.feedback-rounds-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px; 
}
.feedback-rounds-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); 
}
```

```html
<div class="feedback-rounds-container">Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here. Content here.</div>

<br>

<div class="feedback-rounds-container">Content here</div>
```

Comment: Why use a snippet if you don't provide html code?

Comment: Have you tried overflow-y:auto;

Answer (score 0):

Use `auto` instead of `scroll`; this will show a vertical scrollbar **only** if content overflows.

```
.feedback-rounds-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```